# How to access Nested JSON Data via Index, Angular JS, ng-click?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a List of cars assigned to a person for a particular month.  If you search April you will get April data.  How do I access Nested JSON data via Index?

Here's [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSpT2zjut33t8x5hI6U1?p=preview)

```
   $scope.cars = $scope.results[resultIndex].cars.map(function(car) {
          return {
        make: car.Make,
            year: car.Year
          };
        });

   $scope.showCars = function(resultIndex) {
      $scope.cars = $scope.results[resultIndex].cars;
    };

      "April": [{
            "Name": "Tim",
                "Address": "Street",
                "Phone": "111",
                "Status": "Speeding",
                "cars": [
                  {
                    "Make": "Honda",
                    "Year": "2000"
                   }, 
                  {
                    "Make": "Ford",
                    "Year": "2010"
                  },
                  {
                    "Make": "Toyota",
                    "Year": "2004"
                  }

            ]},
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean nested JSON by index, you mean an array inside an object? Like obj = {array: [1,2,3,4]} ?

Comment: I would like to pull the car make and year out...

Answer (score 4):

Theres a few things you should first

- Change the button type to button, otherwise it might assume submit
- Beautify your code http://jsbeautifier.org/

Now to the code, you should really simplify your logic.  Your data structure is all there and you haven't changed it much every time you search for something, so theres no need to map or loop the data - you should only need that if you need to do something with the data.

Your click button function can be as simple as

```
$scope.clickButton = function(enteredValue) {
    $scope.reset();
    $scope.results = data[enteredValue];
}
```

Change ur showCars function to

```
$scope.showCars = function(car) {
    $scope.cars = car;
};
```

in your html simply change the showCars function call to

```
<td ng-click='showCars($index)'>{{result.name}}</td>
```

Remove this, you wont need it

```
$scope.cars = $scope.results[resultIndex].cars.map(function(car) {
      return {
    make: car.Make,
        year: car.Year
      };
    });
```

**EDIT**

Heres the result http://plnkr.co/edit/LGytByq0d3a7AORxXsHa?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Yang.  I tried that but it didn't work.  I'll keep at it.

Comment: Opps, I've given you the wrong plunk, check the updated answer @Angular_Newbie